# Foreign key mismatch SQLite

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I searched all the documentation about this and I can't seem to understans what's the problem, maybe an experienced could help me.

So I'm creating a table called LOCALIZACAO:

```
CREATE TABLE LOCALIZACAO(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
rua TEXT NOT NULL,
codigoPostal TEXT NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (codigoPostal));
```

And this other table that references LOCALIZACAO, called SOCIOLOCALIZACAO:

```
CREATE TABLE SOCIOLOCALIZACAO(
idS INTEGER REFERENCES SOCIO(idS),
idL INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES LOCALIZACAO(idL),
CONSTRAINT pk_SOCIOLOCALIZACAO PRIMARY KEY (idS),
CONSTRAINT fk_SOCIOLOCALIZACAO FOREIGN KEY (idL) REFERENCES LOCALIZACAO(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Altough I'm inserting elements on the LOCALIZACAO table, when I'm inserting on the SOCIOLOCALIZACAO table:

```
INSERT INTO SOCIOLOCALIZACAO VALUES (1,1);
```

I'm given an error

```
foreign key mismatch "SOCIOLOCALIZACAO" referencing "LOCALIZACAO"
```

I'm sure there is the element 1 in SOCIO and in LOCALIZACAO

Here is the SOCIO table:

```
CREATE TABLE SOCIO(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
nome TEXT NOT NULL,
anoDeNascimento INTEGER NOT NULL,
numeroDeSocio INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (numeroDeSocio > 0),
nif INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (nif > 99999999 AND nif < 1000000000),
anoDeVinculacao INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (anoDeNascimento < anoDeVinculacao),
UNIQUE (nome, nif),
UNIQUE (numeroDeSocio));
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: The id column in LOCALIZACAO table is an AUTOINCREMENT, are you sure it has 1 as value? Remove AUTOINCREMENT.and insert manually and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreign key references the fields `idS` and `idL` in table `LOCALIZACAO`. There are no such fields, there's only an `id` field there.

I guess you're only seeing this when inserting records because SQLite is not very pedantic. Other databases wouldn't have let you create such a foreign key.